# Fake Stack Overflow site [facebook.efinancestocks.com]

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

While I was browsing I came across http://facebook.efinancestocks.com/ .
This one seems to look exactly the same as [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com).

It even has lot of exchanges too:

http://meta.efinancestocks.com/
http://www.efinancestocks.com/
http://chat.efinancestocks.com
http://blog.efinancestocks.com
http://careers.efinancestocks.com
http://rads.efinancestocks.com/

Is this site a fake or is Stack Overflow providing API and stuff to re-create its questions/answers/site itself?

**Update**: Found another one.

http://stackoverflow.com.exactgo.com/

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers

Comment: Wow, `rev 2015.6.24.2682` (in the footer) - this is actually quite likely to be a proxy.